# AJAX success with expected 302 redirect?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I am using ajax to POST form data cross domain to a marketing automation program my company uses. It specifically states in the documentation that a 302 response is actually expected when passing data to the url.

Because of the 302 redirect, I can never get the my ajax to hit the "success:" option so I have "complete:" in order to reach the console.log regardless of success or fail. Not sure if this is the best approach.

Code:

```
    $("#button").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var quoteData = $( "form" ).serialize();//the form info stored in a string 

            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",  
                url: 'http://othersiteurl/index.php/leadcapture/save',
                data: quoteData,  //takes all the form data from the variable
                complete: function(){
                            console.log('this is working');// this is where success code will go
                          }
            });
        });
```

Oddly enough, the data from the form inputs make it to the other database upon submission. I am able to view the submission info in the marketing program and it also updates! Any suggestions on how to reach an ajax POST success with a 302?

UPDATE: Code with 302 param:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",  
                url: 'http://othersiteurl/index.php/leadCapture/save', 
                data: quoteData,  //takes all the form data from the variable and passes it to quote.php
                statusCode:{ 302:function(){ alert("yay its a 302"); } }, //doesn't fire alert :-(
                complete: function(){
                            console.log('this is working');
                          }
            });
```

Comment: What about following the redirect? It should lead you to an existing URL with content, which should successfully be requested.

Comment: can you add this in your ajax call as a param - 
statusCode:{
302:function(){
alert("yay its a 302");
}
}

Comment: @Akshay I added your param but it doesn't fire off an alert. Firebug is clearly showing it IS a 302 so i am curious as to why this isn't working.

Comment: @Sven thanks for the input, could you elaborate a little bit on following the redirect?

Comment: You send a POST request, and you get back a redirect status to another URL. You are supposed to GET this URL for the final result. I suppose jQuery should do this automatically. Have you looked at what really happens on the HTTP level? Open your browser debug tool and look at what is sent back and forth between your browser and the server. You should capture the response sent after the POST and include it in your answer.

Comment: @Sven Looking at firebug I am getting nothing back in the response, it's empty.I am however seeing data in response and request headers. Is this what you are referring to? Also, in Chrome looking at the network tab, POST in is red with Status = canceled. It's crazy..the data IS being posted to the other site.Essentially, the action of the form is doing exactly what I want it to do. I am just not sure if triggering what happens next (jQuery animation, fadeOut, ect) on complete vs success or even .done() is the correct way to handle ajax.

Comment: @Akshay statusCode:302 did nothing. Seemed like a good path to take since it is a 302. No dice!

Comment: Can you grab a copy of the response headers and add it to your question?